# User interface appearance changes when view in different system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a newbie in Bootstrap, I'm trying to create a website, but the website appearance is perfect in my laptop which is of 1366 x 768. Any System viewed with lower or higher resolution is resulting changing of the placement of images and div elements.

I wanted to know is there a way to maintain the same appearance in all the system irrespective of the resolution

*Code That I have Tried*

```
<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
             <title>About Us</title>
             <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="css/customized.css" rel="stylesheet">
         </head>
        <body style="background-color:#e1c184;" >
        <div class="page-header no-padding no-margin bck">
         <center>
                 <img   src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </center>
                   </div>
         <nav   style="background-color:#ad802b; border:1px solid  gold;" class="nav navbar-default ">
                  <div class="col-xs-4">            
                      </div>                       
                   <div class="col-xs-8 ">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed  " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resp-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                     <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                           
                    </button>
                         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse backs" id="resp-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                     <ul   class="nav navbar-nav pull-left hidden-xs">
                            <li><a     href="index.html"><span class="links1">Home </span><span class="links1" style="font-size :18px"> &nbsp; |</span></a> </li>
                            <li><a    href="Services.html"><span class="links1">Services </span>  <span class="links1" style="font-size :18px">   &nbsp;&nbsp;|</span></a>  </li>
                            <li><a      href="#"><span class="links1">About Us </span>  <span class="links1" style="font-size :18px"> &nbsp;&nbsp;  |</span></a> </li>
                     <li><a     href="Contact_Us.html"><span class="links1">Contact Us </span> </a> </li>
                        </ul>  
                           <ul   class="nav navbar-nav  pull-left hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md">
                            <li ><a    href="index.html"><span class="links1">Home </span> </a> </li>
                            <li><a   href="Services.html"><span class="links1">Services </span>   </a>  </li>
                            <li><a   href="#"><span class="links1">About Us   </span> </a> </li>
                     <li><a    href="Contact_Us.html"><span class="links1">Contact Us  </span></a> </li>
                        </ul>  
                      </div>   
                </div>
            </nav>
           <br>
          <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
          <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
            <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-10">
               <span  style="font-size:14px;"class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"></span>&nbsp; SANKALAN :
                <div  class="panel panel-warning">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
              </div>
            </div>
<div class="row ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div  style="text-align:justify;" class="text-center alert alert-warning">
                 SANKALAN is one of the beneficiaries of this booming industry as the firm has taken to Industrial Packaging. While the firm undertakes various other Industrial packing activities, the lion's share comes from the news paper sector. SANKALAN was established in the year 1998 under the dynamic leadership of its proprietor Sri Ramesh N. Kale. Since then, the firm has taken a giant's stride towards the growth of this service Industry.
   The industry has contributed immensely towards direct and indirect employment.
                    </div>
            </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs">
                    <div class="bs-example">
    <div style="width:420px; height:215px;" id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000"
      data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Carousel indicators -->
     <!-- <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>-->
      <!-- Carousel items -->
      <div  class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
             <img  style="width:420px; height:215px; border:2px solid gold;"src="images/transport.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img  style="width:420px; height:215px;border:2px solid gold;" src="images/transport1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
         <img  style="width:420px; height:215px; border:2px solid gold;" src="images/transport3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <!--  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a> <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel"
        data-slide="next"> <span
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>-->
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>       
            </div>
    <!-- Repeat -->
           <div class="col-md-5 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                    <div class="bs-example">
    <div style="width:290px; height:180px;" id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000"
      data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Carousel indicators -->
     <!-- <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>-->
      <!-- Carousel items -->
      <div  class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
             <img  style="width:350px; height:180px; border:2px solid gold;"src="images/transport.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img  style="width:350px; height:180px; border:2px solid gold;" src="images/transport1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
         <img  style="width:350px; height:180px; border:2px solid gold;" src="images/transport3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <!--  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a> <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel"
        data-slide="next"> <span
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>-->
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>
    <!-- End of Repeat -->
         <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
    </div>
            </div>
            <br>
<div class="row hidden-xs">
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
                         <div class="bs-example">
    <div style="width:420px; height:235px;" id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000"
      data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Carousel indicators -->
     <!-- <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>-->
      <!-- Carousel items -->
      <div  class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
             <img  style="width:450px; height:235px; border:2px solid gold;"src="images/newspaper_Media3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img  style="width:450px; height:235px; border:2px solid gold;" src="images/newspaper_Media2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
         <img  style="width:450px; height:235px; border:2px solid gold;" src="images/newspaper_Media4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <!--  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a> <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel"
        data-slide="next"> <span
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>-->
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div  style="text-align:justify;" class="text-center alert alert-warning">
                     This is evident from the turnover of Rs. 1.26 Cores achieved by the firm as at the end of March 31st 2015.
           The firm has achieved a turnover of Rs. 1.56 Cores, as on December 31st 2015, which is very encouraging. While the total Turnover is expected to cross the Rs. 1.66 Cores mark, the firm has added a new feather to its cap as a     assignment of packing is offered in six other important cities in Karnataka and hence this Project Report. The firm has already given employment to 69 People in Bangalore and expected to employ 80 people more in different designated cities.
                    </div>
            </div>
         <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
    </div></div>
<!-- Repeat -->
<div class="row hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div  style="text-align:justify;" class="text-center alert alert-warning">
                     This is evident from the turnover of Rs. 1.26 Cores achieved by the firm as at the end of March 31st 2015.
           The firm has achieved a turnover of Rs. 1.56 Cores, as on December 31st 2015, which is very encouraging. While the total Turnover is expected to cross the Rs. 1.66 Cores mark, the firm has added a new feather to its cap as a     assignment of packing is offered in six other important cities in Karnataka and hence this Project Report. The firm has already given employment to 69 People in Bangalore and expected to employ 80 people more in different designated cities.
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                         <div class="bs-example">
    <div style="width:290px; height:180px; " id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000"
      data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Carousel indicators -->
     <!-- <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>-->
      <!-- Carousel items -->
      <div  class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
             <img  style="width:350px; height:180px; border:2px solid gold;"src="images/newspaper_Media3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img  style="width:350px; height:180px; border:2px solid gold;" src="images/newspaper_Media2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
         <img  style="width:350px; height:180px;  border:2px solid gold;" src="images/newspaper_Media4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <!--  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a> <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel"
        data-slide="next"> <span
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>-->
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>
            <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
    </div></div>

<!-- end of repeat -->




      <br>
            <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
          <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
            <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-10">
               <span  style="font-size:14px;"class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"></span>&nbsp; OBJECTIVE :
                <div  class="panel panel-warning">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
              </div>


            </div>   

        <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
          <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div  style="text-align:justify;" class="text-center alert alert-warning">
                   <p> India is one of the developing countries in the world. Our country has made progress in leaps and bounds in major sectors. The super powers are watching us closely and have recognised India as a potential Super Power in the making.
                        </p>

                        <p>The Survey has witnessed the all-round growth in technologies, pacier than expected. The multinational companies have made their presence felt through huge investments in India. </p>

                    </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div  style="text-align:justify;" class="text-center alert alert-warning">
                  <p> Joint ventures in various fields are on the rise. The multinational companies are looking at us for marketing their products as there is a huge scope here.</p>
                        <p>Bangalore is identified very easily in the world map as the silicon city. The city has an unique reputation of being called the "Garden City of India.
</p>
<br>
  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>

                    </div>



        </div>
        <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
              </div>


            </div>   
<br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
          <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div  style="text-align:justify;" class="text-center alert alert-warning">
                   <p> Bangalore is one of the most cosmopolitan cities in India and has destination of earning the highest foreign exchange in the IT sector
                        </p>

                        <p>Another Industry which has drawn attention of every on is the news paper media. This industry has marked its success through quality printing and coverage.
 </p>

  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div  style="text-align:justify;" class="text-center alert alert-warning">
                  <p> As the literacy level has gone up, the number of people reading the newspapers is also in the rise. The circulation has gone up by many folds. This is the largest media for advertisements and cost effective too. 
</p>
                        <p>Bangalore because of the presence of the major news Papers, is one of the highest circulating cities in India The industry provides opportunities to activities like Transportation, Distribution and Packing.


</p>



                    </div>



        </div>
        <div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-md-1">
        </div>
              </div>


            </div>   



<br>




<div id="footer" class="page-header hidden-xs" >
      <footer  style=" background-color:#ad802b;position: absolute; bottom: 0;  width: 100%;  height: 30px; "  class="footer">

          <div class="col-md-1" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4" >
          <div   style="color : #FFFFFF; margin-top:5px;" class="container-fluid">
        <strong  style="color : #FFFFFF;" > Copyright &copy; 2016-17 <a href="#">  </strong>  
              </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4" >
          <div   style="color : #000000; margin-top:5px;" class="container-fluid pull-right">
              <strong  style="color : #000000;" >Designed By :  <a href="http://msdesigns.co.in/"> <span class="links1"> MsDesigns co.</span></a> </strong>  
              </div>   
                </div>


      </footer>
   </div>        
 <!-- Repeat -->
    <div id="footer" class="page-header hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg   ">
      <footer  style=" background-color:#ad802b;position: absolute; bottom: 0;  width: 100%;  height: 30px; "  class="footer">


          <div   style="color : #000000; margin-top:5px; font-size: 12px;" class="container-fluid">
        <strong  style="color : #000000;" class="pull-left"> Copyright &copy; 2016-17 <a href="#">  </strong>  
          <div class="pull-right" >  <strong  style="color : #000000;" > &nbsp; Designed By : <a href="http://msdesigns.co.in/"><span  style="color : #000000;" > MsDesigns co.</span> </strong>  </div>

              </div>
                </div>

              </div>   



      </footer>
   </div>        



    <!-- End of Repeat-->




         <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>  
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>



        </html>
```

- Required help in a concept that will maintain the placement of all the elements like div , images , navbar and so on in same place in all system mainly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is an responsive CSS framework, in other words it adapts to the different screen sizes.

In your case, reason your layout is changing is because your classes such as "col-md-1" and "col-md-4" are just defining what size the element should have in screens larger than 992px. If the screen is less than 992px all elements with a "col-md-X" is set to 100% of screen width.
To change this behavior you have to add a class like "col-sm-3" (larger than 768px) or "col-xs-3" (less than 768px).

> So to keep the same appearance just change all the classes "col-md-X" to col-xs-X"

*Classes like these `hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg` hide elements in different screen sizes so you'd have to remove them as well*

Comment: Hi Sprazer just need one more advice.  I followed your ideas and was successful but not able get the required output in system which has 1920 x 800. So what can I do in this situation. How to use media queries. Please guide me

Comment: I don't know how to answer that. I recommend using google and take one "error" at the time. Bootstrap and media queries are VERY well documented.